# Classic asp problem

Tags: asp-classic

I have this problem with my .Asp file. I get an error saying 'GetFrontpageInfo' is undefined.

This is the code:

http://www.kollelbaaleibatim.com/Content_of_asp_file.txt

click "view source" to see the code.

TY

Comment: The problem is that you are using ASP. *I've got the same problem...*

Comment: Couldn't you describe your problem better than "Classic ASP Problem"? Everyone who asks an ASP question here has a "Classic ASP Problem".

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to call a *server side* function from client side code.

The `onLoad` event is fired in the browser, so a client side function called `GetFrontpageInfo` cannot be found.

Remove the attribute and place the following at the bottom of your page:

This way, you are calling server side code from the server side.

**Update**:

Looking at the code again - you are also trying to call in client side in the onClick event of your input button.

An additional problem is that you are trying to call *alert* on the server side. This is not possible.

Perhaps you should change your function from server side (enclosed in `<%%>`) to client side script, and return the call to the `onload` event in the body tag:

```
<script language="vbscript>

     sub GetFrontpageInfo()

        ShortTitleLeftCar = "temp value in variable"
        messagebox(ShortTitleLeftCar)

     end sub
</script>
```

You seem to be mixing VBScript and Javascript, as well as client side and server side code.

Comment: I put it at the bottom of the page, right after the tag </html>, and now i'm not getting the error, but the function is not fired.

Comment: Ok. I'm starting to get what you are saying. I guess I spent way to much time doing asp.net. I'm loosing my classic asp skills. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you function GetFrontpageInfo is defined as a server-side method, but you are calling it on the client side.  `<body onload="GetFrontpageInfo">` is looking for a Javascript function called GetFrontpageInfo

Comment: @Glennular - if this is IE, it _can_ also be a VBScript function.